# Compute $P(X + Y = 3)$.

Tags: probability

Let $X ∼ Geo(1/4)$ and $Y ∼ Geo(1/2)$. The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Compute $P(X + Y = 3)$.

For a geometric distribution $P(X=k)=P(1-p)^{k-1}$ where $k=3$ but which value should I take for $p$? The sum of the two $p$s ($1/4+1/2$)? I tried but it's wrong, can someone help me? (Correct answer is $5/32$)

Comment: Hint: the sum of two geometric random variables is not a geometric random variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- You could calculate $P(X+Y=3)$ $=P(X=0,Y=3)+P(X=1,Y=2)+P(X=2,Y=1)+P(X=3,Y=0)$
- Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent $P(X=x,Y=y)=P(X=x)P(Y=y)$

Comment: Thank you for the comment but if I compute it, my result is 65/192 and not 5/32.
I have $1*9/64+1/2*3/16+1/4*1/4+1/8*1/3$, where I'm wrong?

Comment: For $P(X=0)$ you seem to be using $1$.  Depending on which definition of the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) you are using, I would have thought it should be either $0$ or $\frac14$.  Similar issues arise with the other parts of your calculation

Comment: I'm using $P(X=k)=P(1-p)^{k-1}$ is not correct? Which one should I use?

Comment: Ahh I see to point, my definition is from k=1, the other that you use from k=0, I'll try with the other definition :)

Comment: Now it's correct, I just use the definition with $k-1$ at the exponent for $k=1,2,3...$ but I didn't consider the case $P(X=0)$ and $P(Y=0)$. But now that I discover this thing for the geometric distribution I have duct, if I want to calculate $P(X>k)$ it is $(1-p)^{k-1}$ or just $(1-p)^{k}$? (using the definition for geometric distribution described above)

Comment: If you are using the version counting the number of attempts where the smallest possible value is $1$, the probability $P(X>k) = (1-p)^k$. If you are using the version counting the number of failures before a success where the smallest possible value is $0$, the probability $P(X>k) = (1-p)^{k+1}$

Comment: Thank you again :)